# Code is not capturing 404 errors in angularjs $http request

Tags: javascript, json, angularjs, rest, http

I'm trying to add some error handling to an angularjs app I wrote about a year ago. For some REST API calls, the back end returns a 404 that I want to silently fix up by simply returning an empty list/array. But I'm not able to capture the 404 error and I don't understand why it's not working.

I'm following the docs [here](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$http)  and I expect the `response` of the `errorCallback` to be an object with a `status` property. Instead, it has a SyntaxError constructor with properties named fileName, lineNumber, columnNumber, and message. The message is a JSON.parse error.

Now I can -- kind of -- understand why there is a JSON parse error: there is no data! But the response status is being lost and my code cannot distinguish between a 404 and other errors that I do not want to silently fix up.

What am I missing here? And where is it documented? The angular docs seem incorrect -- unless I'm somehow reading them wrong.

```
$http({
    method: 'GET',
    url: myRestApiUri
})
.then(
    function successCallback( response ) {
        handlers.success(response);
    },
    function errorCallback( response  ) {
        if( response.status === 404 ) {
            handlers.success( [] );
        }
        else {
            handlers.error(response);
        }
    }
)
```

**EDIT:** After receiving some feedback, I realized that I'm using an older version of angular. So I'm revising my question slightly: Does the latest (or any newer) version of angular implement the http error trapping correctly? I don't want to install a new angular and rework my code for API changes, only to find out then that the newer angular has the same problem.

Comment: What do you get in response when you make the call directly in the browser?   Like: http://yourrestserver/option"

Comment: What version of angular are you using verses the version the docs are referencing? Its got me in the past where the docs default to the latest version and i'm using an older one which does things differently.

Comment: @Charlie H, the response body is "Not Found". So no surprise that JSON.parse pukes on that. My goal here -- and what I expected the http error callback to do -- was to trap the http error, not a json parse error.

Comment: @ste2425, Good catch. I'm using 1.3, which defines the callback with a different signature `function(data, status, headers, config)`. But even so, the core problem/question remains the same. I expect to see the status parameter with a value of 404. But instead the data parameter is a SyntaxError object. I want to trap the 404 *before* angular goes trying to parse the server's error text as if it were JSON.

Comment: Dang, I got this problem 1 year ago with 1.4, but I didn't have time to investigate it and had to move on to new project. Now I am using 1.5, still the same problem, Angular try to parse the 404 response and give that error